# Which kernel version to use if the latest has problems and what's next?

Tags: boot, kernel

I had problems when I installed the latest updates on Ubuntu 12.04 a few days ago. My computer didn't boot correctly.

I read many questions here and I got to work with an older kernel version: 3.2.0-31-generic

The thing is that I know I can work selecting this version each time I turn on the computer, but how can I really **fix** the problem with the newer kernel? I don't want to select the older version each time.

Where can I report that? How long am I going to have to use the older version? I believe there is a lack of information in these cases.

Besides, sometimes I have [another problems](http://placerdigital.net/up/boot.jpg) when I boot... it occurs maybe 1 out of 4 times, but I'll post that in a different question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-X linux-headers-X` where X is the version that is giving you issues. Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. You may want to try installing 3.2.0-32-generic which is the latest version for 12.04.

Comment: Thank you, @cogitoergosum. The problem is that the 3.2.0-32-generic is precisely the one causing the problems, so I'm using 3.2.0-31-generic but I still wonder what's next. I mean... will I have to use that version forever? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to retry the 3.2.0-32-generic installation. If you are adventurous, perhaps 3.6.3 may work better (http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/install-linux-kernel-363-in-ubuntu.html). Am assuming you are running the desktop version (not server). Good luck.