# System boots to grub prompt after kernel upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel

I have a venerable Dell Latitude D610 which is running Ubuntu bionic (18.04.6 LTS) - i386. It gets used only occasionally and generally boots without a problem; however, from time to time I'm notified at boot time that updates are available, and if it's prescribed, the kernel, kernel modules, initrd and other relevant files get updated.

On occasion it looks as if grub.cfg gets hozed, and I'm dropped to the `grub>` prompt at startup. I know how to manually spec the kernel and root filesystem and boot the system from this prompt (although it's a PITA and I have to look the details each time). After I get the system back on its feet I can run `/usr/sbin/update-grub` and all is well until the next kernel upgrade.

Is there a way to get update-grub invoked automatically in the appropriate place after a kernel upgrade so that I don't have to go through the tedious process of manually setting up a proper boot when this happens?

This little Dell only has year or so left on it, after which the LTS release will expire and there will be no more releases for the i386 architecture, but it's still useful, and I'd like to fix this bug.

Comment: If it's a bug, it should be reported on a bug tracker such as launchpad - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs   You weren't specific as to which kernels tack you were using (*Ubuntu LTS provides two choices but you didn't say which you're using*)   FYI:  `update-grub` is automatically performed when kernel changes are made; if it's not taking effect it's possible because you're system is dual boot, and the Ubuntu install doesn't control the booting...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel update (64) will not boot. How can I automatically boot with earlier version? U12.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/478028/kernel-update-64-will-not-boot-how-can-i-automatically-boot-with-earlier-vers)